# How to turn off mmap usage for malloc() in multithread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, malloc, mmap

Seems like `malloc()` prefer to use `mmap()` to allocate space in multi-thread program. I just tried set `M_TRIM_THRESHOLD` and `M_MMAP_MAX` to turn off `mmap` usage but failed:

```
// Turn off malloc trimming.
mallopt(M_TRIM_THRESHOLD, -1);

// Turn off mmap usage.
mallopt(M_MMAP_MAX, 0);
```

A simple test piece of code is as following:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void alloc_assert()
{
    // Turn off malloc trimming.
    mallopt(M_TRIM_THRESHOLD, -1);

    // Turn off mmap usage.
    mallopt(M_MMAP_MAX, 0);

    void* p = malloc(100);

    printf("size_t(p): %zu\n", size_t(p));

    assert(size_t(p) < 0x100000000000l);
}

void* thread_func(void *arg)
{
    alloc_assert();

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thr[2];
    int data = 0;

    // Multi-thread enabled.
    if (pthread_create(&thr[0], NULL, &thread_func, (void*) &data) != 0)
    {
        printf("Create thread error\n");
    }

    pthread_join(thr[0], NULL);

    //alloc_assert();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as following:

```
size_t(p): 140154111002816
a.out: main.cpp:37: void alloc_assert(): Assertion `size_t(p) < 0x100000000000l' failed.
[1]    154060 abort      ./a.out
```

`malloc()` allocated the space on a high-address instead of normal heap address. However, if we change the code in `main()` to following:

```
int main()
{
    alloc_assert();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
size_t(p): 31775776
```

Instead of using `mmap()`, `malloc()` allocated the space on a normal heap. I wanna if it's possible to turn off `mmap()` usage for `malloc()` in multi-thread program?

My environment configurations:

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
Linux fsdev32 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: *Why* would you want to disable `mmap()`ed heap space?

Comment: @EOF We reserved addresses greater than 0x100000000000l for storing our system data. malloc() via mmap() will destroy our data as it would take these addresses as well.

Comment: @JimMa: If you need special address ranges for yourself, mmap them first.

Comment: not using mmap would mean only sbrk?

Comment: @Adalcar Yep. At least malloc() in multithread code block.

Comment: @ZanLynx That might be a potential solution but we have to change our system design. And can we guarantee that malloc() will never use the addresses were mmapped but have not been read/written? AFAK, mmap won't allocate the real space until a read/write operation happens.

Comment: Can't you use mmap to request specific pages?

Comment: @JimMa: `mmap()` with a `NULL` first argument will not replace an existing `mmap()`ed area. AFAIK, `malloc()` will use `mmap()` this way.

Comment: @JimMa: I don't know what your system design is. Do the mmap with PROT_NONE flags at the very beginning of main. Later in your program if you are actually allocating virtual pages in that memory range, you just change your mmap calls to use MAP_FIXED and it will overwrite the old mmap setting for the new call. But if you are using that high range just as some kind of marker on pointers, just leave the high range mmap alone and it will block other users of it.

Comment: @JimMa: The problem with trying to fix malloc to not mmap is that malloc is not the only thing using mmap. You might upgrade some other library in the future and it will mmap on its own, bypassing malloc, and return a pointer to you from the high range...then what do you do.

Comment: @JimMa: I have to apologize. I thought this would be straight-forward to do. So I wrote code to do it. But Linux won't allow me to fill in the biggest gap from 00007fff533b6000 to ffffffffff600000 because even though its an empty map it claims its out of memory trying to allocate 184 petabytes.

Comment: Running your program through `strace`, I can see `mmap(NULL, 134217728, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7f17a4b00000`, so it looks like glibc used `mmap` to serve that request despite your requesting that it shan't do that.

Comment: I see the same happening when setting the `MALLOC_MMAP_MAX_=0` environment variable, which according to [`man mallopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) should also have the desired effect. Perhaps the man page is wrong and glibc doesn't actually respect these requests?

Comment: Also note that you're not checking the return values of `mallopt()` (it could fail), but I've added checks and they don't return errors in this case.

Answer (score 3):

#### Summary

It looks like the reason is that glibc's malloc uses multiple malloc "arenas", and gives each new thread its own arena, no matter what you set `M_MMAP_MAX` to.

And if there's space in that arena, glibc will give it to your `malloc()` requests.

You can disable that with `mallopt(M_ARENA_MAX, 1)`.

#### Details

I confirmed this by importing `#include <malloc.h>` (glibc specific) and changing your code to show [`malloc_stats()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html) statistics:

```
malloc_stats();
puts("");
void* p = malloc(100);
malloc_stats();
```

This prints:

```
Arena 0:
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =       1328
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =       1328
max mmap regions =          0
max mmap bytes   =          0

Arena 0:
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =       1328
Arena 1:
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =       2336
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =     270336
in use bytes     =       3664
max mmap regions =          0
max mmap bytes   =          0
```

We can see how a new `Arena 1` was added with `135168` many bytes.

In `strace -fy -e mmap ./yourprogram`, we can see the creation of this arena:

```
[pid  8704] mmap(NULL, 134217728, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7efefe1a7000
[pid  8704] munmap(0x7efefe1a7000, 31821824) = 0
[pid  8704] munmap(0x7eff04000000, 35287040) = 0
[pid  8704] mprotect(0x7eff00000000, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0

size_t(p): 139633681762496; address: 0x7eff000008c0
```

So looks like glibc `mmap`s some memory for the new arena, frees some part of it, and then `mprotect()`s `135168` many bytes -- just as much as that arena shows up as in `malloc_stats()`.

This suggests to me that [`man mallopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) saying

```
Setting this parameter to 0 disables the use of mmap(2)
for servicing large allocation requests.
```

isn't quite true: It will still `mmap` when it wants to create a new arena.

You can apparently avoid this using:

```
mallopt(M_ARENA_MAX, 1);
```